# NativeScript exclude *.js from /src

Tags: nativescript

Base on the tutorial, after execute the `tns run ios`. Compiled *js will allocate the /src folder.

How do I exclude the *.js compiled at /src folder?
Put it at webpack.config.js ?

Comment: Sorry exclude *js from /app folder

Comment: You need *.js files in app folder cause cli will pick them up for app and copied to platforms forlders or rewriting some part of tns cli

Comment: The TS files will be transpiled to JS and all the needed JS (without the TS) will be included in the `platforms/ios` folder (if using webpack then you will end with one bundled file) - so you don't need to exclude anything. You can still ignore the *.JS file from the app folder from your source control - for example: https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/.gitignore#L10-L11

Answer (score 1):

As Nick mentioned *.js files are what NativeScript uses to run your program, so you can't get rid of them. However when using an editor such as NativeScript, you can configure your settings to ignore and not display the .js files - makes for much easier navigation of your code!

Open Code > Preferences > Settings and add the following lines

`"files.exclude": {
        "**/*.js": true
    }`

Hope this helps.